# Tensorflow: strided_slice slicing error with while loop

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I've created a rather complex seq2seq type model (based on "A Neural Transducer"), and in the latest version of Tensorflow, the following code returns the error:

```
Cannot use 'transducer_training/while/rnn/strided_slice' as input to 'gradients/transducer_training/while/rnn/while/Select_1_grad/Select/f_acc' because 'transducer_training/while/rnn/strided_slice' is in a while loop
```

The code worked before, only since the latest version has it stopped:
numpy (1.14.0) 
protobuf (3.5.1) tensorflow (1.5.0) tensorflow-gpu
    (1.3.0) tensorflow-tensorboard (1.5.1) Ubuntu version 16.04.3 LTS
    (Xenial Xerus)

Code (To get the error just copy, paste and run it):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import LSTMCell, LSTMStateTuple
from tensorflow.python.layers import core as layers_core

# NOTE: Time major

# ---------------- Constants Manager ----------------------------
class ConstantsManager(object):
    def __init__(self, input_dimensions, input_embedding_size, inputs_embedded, encoder_hidden_units,
                 transducer_hidden_units, vocab_ids, input_block_size, beam_width):
        assert transducer_hidden_units == encoder_hidden_units, 'Encoder and transducer have to have the same amount' \
                                                                'of hidden units'
        self.input_dimensions = input_dimensions
        self.vocab_ids = vocab_ids
        self.E_SYMBOL = len(self.vocab_ids)
        self.vocab_ids.append('E_SYMBOL')
        self.GO_SYMBOL = len(self.vocab_ids)
        self.vocab_ids.append('GO_SYMBOL')
        self.vocab_size = len(self.vocab_ids)
        self.input_embedding_size = input_embedding_size
        self.inputs_embedded = inputs_embedded
        self.encoder_hidden_units = encoder_hidden_units
        self.transducer_hidden_units = transducer_hidden_units
        self.input_block_size = input_block_size
        self.beam_width = beam_width
        self.batch_size = 1  # Cannot be increased, see paper
        self.log_prob_init_value = 0

# ----------------- Model ---------------------------------------


class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, cons_manager):
        self.var_list = []
        self.cons_manager = cons_manager
        self.max_blocks, self.inputs_full_raw, self.transducer_list_outputs, self.start_block, self.encoder_hidden_init,\
            self.trans_hidden_init, self.logits, self.encoder_hidden_state_new, \
            self.transducer_hidden_state_new, self.train_saver = self.build_full_transducer()

        self.targets, self.train_op, self.loss = self.build_training_step()

    def build_full_transducer(self):
        with tf.variable_scope('transducer_training'):

            embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([self.cons_manager.vocab_size,
                                                        self.cons_manager.input_embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
                                     dtype=tf.float32,
                                     name='embedding')
            # Inputs
            max_blocks = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name='max_blocks')  # total amount of blocks to go through
            if self.cons_manager.inputs_embedded is True:
                input_type = tf.float32
            else:
                input_type = tf.int32
            inputs_full_raw = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, self.cons_manager.batch_size,
                                                    self.cons_manager.input_dimensions), dtype=input_type,
                                             name='inputs_full_raw')  # shape [max_time, 1, input_dims]
            transducer_list_outputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                                     name='transducer_list_outputs')  # amount to output per block
            start_block = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name='transducer_start_block')  # where to start the input

            encoder_hidden_init = tf.placeholder(shape=(2, 1, self.cons_manager.encoder_hidden_units), dtype=tf.float32,
                                                 name='encoder_hidden_init')
            trans_hidden_init = tf.placeholder(shape=(2, 1, self.cons_manager.transducer_hidden_units), dtype=tf.float32,
                                               name='trans_hidden_init')

            # Temporary constants, maybe changed during inference
            end_symbol = tf.get_variable(name='end_symbol',
                                         initializer=tf.constant_initializer(self.cons_manager.vocab_size),
                                         shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)

            # Turn inputs into tensor which is easily readable#

            inputs_full = tf.reshape(inputs_full_raw, shape=[-1, self.cons_manager.input_block_size,
                                                             self.cons_manager.batch_size,
                                                             self.cons_manager.input_dimensions])

            # Outputs
            outputs_ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=max_blocks)

            init_state = (start_block, outputs_ta, encoder_hidden_init, trans_hidden_init)

            # Initiate cells, NOTE: if there is a future error, put these back inside the body function
            encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=self.cons_manager.encoder_hidden_units)
            transducer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.cons_manager.transducer_hidden_units)

            def cond(current_block, outputs_int, encoder_hidden, trans_hidden):
                return current_block < start_block + max_blocks

            def body(current_block, outputs_int, encoder_hidden, trans_hidden):

                # --------------------- ENCODER ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                encoder_inputs = inputs_full[current_block]
                encoder_inputs_length = [tf.shape(encoder_inputs)[0]]
                encoder_hidden_state = encoder_hidden

                if self.cons_manager.inputs_embedded is True:
                    encoder_inputs_embedded = encoder_inputs
                else:
                    encoder_inputs = tf.reshape(encoder_inputs, shape=[-1, self.cons_manager.batch_size])
                    encoder_inputs_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, encoder_inputs)

                # Build model

                # Build previous state
                encoder_hidden_c, encoder_hidden_h = tf.split(encoder_hidden_state, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=0)
                encoder_hidden_c = tf.reshape(encoder_hidden_c, shape=[-1, self.cons_manager.encoder_hidden_units])
                encoder_hidden_h = tf.reshape(encoder_hidden_h, shape=[-1, self.cons_manager.encoder_hidden_units])
                encoder_hidden_state_t = LSTMStateTuple(encoder_hidden_c, encoder_hidden_h)

                #   encoder_outputs: [max_time, batch_size, num_units]
                encoder_outputs, encoder_hidden_state_new = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                    encoder_cell, encoder_inputs_embedded,
                    sequence_length=encoder_inputs_length, time_major=True,
                    dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=encoder_hidden_state_t)

                # Modify output of encoder_hidden_state_new so that it can be fed back in again without problems.
                encoder_hidden_state_new = tf.concat([encoder_hidden_state_new.c, encoder_hidden_state_new.h], axis=0)
                encoder_hidden_state_new = tf.reshape(encoder_hidden_state_new,
                                                      shape=[2, -1, self.cons_manager.encoder_hidden_units])

                # --------------------- TRANSDUCER --------------------------------------------------------------------
                encoder_raw_outputs = encoder_outputs
                # Save/load the state as one tensor, use encoder state as init if this is the first block
                trans_hidden_state = tf.cond(current_block > 0, lambda: trans_hidden, lambda: encoder_hidden_state_new)
                transducer_amount_outputs = transducer_list_outputs[current_block - start_block]

                # Model building
                helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(
                    embedding=embeddings,
                    start_tokens=tf.tile([self.cons_manager.GO_SYMBOL],
                                         [self.cons_manager.batch_size]),  # TODO: check if this looks good
                    end_token=end_symbol)  # vocab size, so that it doesn't prematurely end the decoding

                attention_states = tf.transpose(encoder_raw_outputs,
                                                [1, 0, 2])  # attention_states: [batch_size, max_time, num_units]

                attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.LuongAttention(
                    self.cons_manager.encoder_hidden_units, attention_states)

                decoder_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(
                    transducer_cell,
                    attention_mechanism,
                    attention_layer_size=self.cons_manager.transducer_hidden_units)

                projection_layer = layers_core.Dense(self.cons_manager.vocab_size, use_bias=False)

                # Build previous state
                trans_hidden_c, trans_hidden_h = tf.split(trans_hidden_state, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=0)
                trans_hidden_c = tf.reshape(trans_hidden_c, shape=[-1, self.cons_manager.transducer_hidden_units])
                trans_hidden_h = tf.reshape(trans_hidden_h, shape=[-1, self.cons_manager.transducer_hidden_units])
                trans_hidden_state_t = LSTMStateTuple(trans_hidden_c, trans_hidden_h)

                decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
                    decoder_cell, helper,
                    decoder_cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32).clone(cell_state=trans_hidden_state_t),
                    output_layer=projection_layer)

                outputs, transducer_hidden_state_new, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder,
                                                                                            output_time_major=True,
                                                                                            maximum_iterations=transducer_amount_outputs)
                logits = outputs.rnn_output  # logits of shape [max_time,batch_size,vocab_size]
                decoder_prediction = outputs.sample_id  # For debugging

                # Modify output of transducer_hidden_state_new so that it can be fed back in again without problems.
                transducer_hidden_state_new = tf.concat(
                    [transducer_hidden_state_new[0].c, transducer_hidden_state_new[0].h],
                    axis=0)
                transducer_hidden_state_new = tf.reshape(transducer_hidden_state_new,
                                                         shape=[2, -1, self.cons_manager.transducer_hidden_units])


                # Note the outputs
                outputs_int = outputs_int.write(current_block - start_block, logits)

                return current_block + 1, outputs_int, encoder_hidden_state_new, transducer_hidden_state_new

            _, outputs_final, encoder_hidden_state_new, transducer_hidden_state_new = \
                tf.while_loop(cond, body, init_state, parallel_iterations=1)

            # Process outputs
            outputs = outputs_final.concat()
            logits = tf.reshape(
                outputs,
                shape=(-1, 1, self.cons_manager.vocab_size))  # And now its [max_output_time, batch_size, vocab]

            # For loading the model later on
            logits = tf.identity(logits, name='logits')
            encoder_hidden_state_new = tf.identity(encoder_hidden_state_new, name='encoder_hidden_state_new')
            transducer_hidden_state_new = tf.identity(transducer_hidden_state_new, name='transducer_hidden_state_new')

        train_saver = tf.train.Saver()  # For now save everything

        return max_blocks, inputs_full_raw, transducer_list_outputs, start_block, encoder_hidden_init,\
            trans_hidden_init, logits, encoder_hidden_state_new, transducer_hidden_state_new, train_saver

    def build_training_step(self):
        targets = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='targets')
        targets_one_hot = tf.one_hot(targets, depth=self.cons_manager.vocab_size, dtype=tf.float32)

        targets_one_hot = tf.Print(targets_one_hot, [targets], message='Targets: ', summarize=10)
        targets_one_hot = tf.Print(targets_one_hot, [tf.argmax(self.logits, axis=2)], message='Argmax: ', summarize=10)

        stepwise_cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=targets_one_hot,
                                                                         logits=self.logits)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(stepwise_cross_entropy)
        train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
        return targets, train_op, loss


constants_manager = ConstantsManager(input_dimensions=1, input_embedding_size=11, inputs_embedded=False,
                                     encoder_hidden_units=100, transducer_hidden_units=100, vocab_ids=[0, 1, 2],
                                     input_block_size=1, beam_width=5)
model = Model(cons_manager=constants_manager)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encounter a similar problem recently when I put a `dynamic_rnn` inside a `scan` (i.e. a while loop). It seems that the bug was introduced only in TensorFlow 1.5. You can try downgrade your TensorFlow version to 1.4 or upgrade to 1.6. Both should work.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the error seems to be raised incorrectly (see github issue in comments). In general, however, such errors mean the following:

The usage pattern that the error message is complaining about was always illegal. Earlier versions of TensorFlow just did not have good checks for it.

The core of the problem is that in TensorFlow's execution model, you cannot use a tensor that you create inside a while loop, outside of it. For a simple illustration of this, take a look at this [test case](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f0a965f268c0527704469d9c9a68acb9a1647afa/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/control_flow_ops_py_test.py#L2866).

You can just disable the check by immediately returning from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f0a965f268c0527704469d9c9a68acb9a1647afa/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_util.py#L166), but your computation graph will be malformed, which can lead to undefined behavior.

The correct fix is to add all the tensors that you want to access outside of the while loop (outside of `cond` and `body` functions) to the `loop_vars` and use them as returned from the [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop).

Comment: Are you sure? The only tensor being used is the one containing the logits, which is used as a loop variable.

Comment: You are right, it does appear like a bug in TensorFlow. I filed a bug report for it. There is no simple workaround besides disabling the check in TF source code. Issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17199

Comment: Thank you! I had also opened an issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17045 but didn't get any response.